# How to handle development to production process with multiple AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, process, aws-mobilehub

I'm using **AWS mobileHub** to create an hybrid app with **Ionic 3.**
I don't get how we can handle the **production process**, Im using all kind of aws services :

- AWS MobileHub
- AWS Cognito (User login/logout)
- AWS API Gateway (Using Lambdas to execute databases request)
- AWS Lambdas (Call DynamoDB tables and MYSQL RDS Table, using VPC)
- AWS DynamoDB (Store some user info and IOT data)
- AWS RDS (Store relational data in MySQL)

### Do we have a way to put everything in **production** ? Here is the idea :

- Customer will view the v1.x of the app, and meanwhile the
  customer is using the v1.x of the app, I want to be able to continue
  the development of the v1.x+1 without being afraid of breaking the
  prod services.

I know that API Gateway has a "Stage" system I can use, for example I could create a "developement" and "production" stage, but what about others services ? which are most of the time linked with API Gateway.

### Here is my idea so far, but I think this is not optimal :

- Create another aws account, dedicated to production, and duplicate all of my services on this account.When I want to deploy a new version I could update all the aws services and push the new code. 
  **Problem :** Its seems not efficient because I will need to manually modify the services one by one and that can lead to a lot of errors (forget something, need to update services in a certain orders..)

Any best practices ? Any ideas ? 
I really need to find a strong deployment process.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I'm going to implement and to try, I will let you know if this is efficient.

[Gitflow diagram picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xul9.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

one of the things you could do is create multiple Mobile Hub projects - one for prod, one for staging. Youu can then export the prod project and import it into the staging project.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a solution for the mobile hub side..
When you export and import a mobile hub project, everything is created again ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to sign up to a beta please email nikhil@live.ca

Answer (score 0):

This and more can be done today with feature branch deployments with the Amplify Console: https://console.amplify.aws